# Wrapping long line of tables with varying heights

Tags: html, css

I'm wrapping an image caption under an image. There are many pairs of these images and captions.

```
<div class="book">
    <img alt="cover"><br>
    <div>
      <b>Title of Book</b><br>
      Some extra info, maybe.
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.book {
    display: table;
    float: left;
}
.book img {
    height: 300px;
}
.book div {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrtn/Q4WBU/). I float the tables left to line each row up against the side of the screen. One of the boxes gets caught because the height of the box to its left is more than the height of the others.

**How can I make each row of boxes line up with the left side of the screen?**

It should look something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrtn/Q5ct3/3/), just with the ability to adapt to different caption heights without an explicit global height.

---

I set all of the images to a constant height, but I don't know their widths. There also might be a long caption, so I need that to wrap to the image width. I've tried

- setting `.book div` to a constant height, but that doesn't adapt to a tall caption ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrtn/Q5ct3/3/))
- using a flexbox, which works, but I'm looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both;` to you book class

Like so:

```
.book {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I don't want each book on a separate line, I just want them to wrap over to the side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I added a container and a new class, see working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4WBU/2/)**

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Comment: I'm trying to let the boxes wrap themselves to the next row when they reach the right side of the screen. Each row should start at the left side of the screen.